# Property of preimage of a value in the range of a $0/1$ loss function

Tags: general-topology

Let $L(\bar{\boldsymbol{w}})$ is an arbitrary $0/1$ loss function (use in perceptron algorithm). Let $v$ is a value of its range. My question is about the property of the set $L^{-1}(v)$. Is it a connected set?

Definition of 0/1 loss function. Let $D = \{(\boldsymbol{x_1},y_1),...,(\boldsymbol{x_N},y_N)\}$, where $\boldsymbol{x_i}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y_i\in \{-1,1\}$. Let $f:=\boldsymbol{w\cdot x}+w_0$, where $\boldsymbol{w,x}\in \mathbb{R}^n, w_0\in \mathbb{R}$, "$\cdot$" is dot product. With $\boldsymbol{w}=(w_1,...,w_n),\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,...,x_n),$ define $\bar{\boldsymbol{w}}:=(w_0,w_1,...,w_n),\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}:=(x_0=1,x_1,...,x_n).$
Then $f$ can rewrite as $f=\bar{\boldsymbol{w}}\cdot \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$. The $0/1$ loss function with respect to $D$   is defined as $L(\bar{\boldsymbol{w}}):=$ the number of $(x_i,y_i)\in D$ such that $f(\bar{\boldsymbol{x_i}}).y_i<0$.

Comment: Would you describe the domain, codomain and the mapping for those who do not about that 0/1 stuff.

Comment: @William Elliot, I will put definition of $0/1$ loss function in my question

Comment: How is undecipherable f a hyperplane?  Is x a scalar, w,w0 n-vectors?  Then f is just a vector.  How is f(x).y defined?

Comment: Sorry, I give a wrong definition. Check my edited question

Comment: What is bar x_i?  As f is a scalar, what does f(thing) mean?

Comment: @William Elliot, $\boldsymbol{x_i}$ can be represented as $\boldsymbol{x_i}=(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n})$ for some $x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n}\in \mathbb{R}$, by definition of $\boldsymbol{\bar{x}}$ in my question, we have $\bar{\boldsymbol{x_i}}=(1,x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n})$. Since $f=\boldsymbol{w}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{w_0}=\boldsymbol{\bar{w}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\bar{x}}$, so  $f(\boldsymbol{\bar{x_i}})=\boldsymbol{\bar{w}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\bar{x_i}}$

Comment: Are intending that n = N and to define f as f:R^n -> R, x -> w$\cdot$x + w_0, ie f(x) = w$\cdot$x + w_0?

Comment: @William Elliot, $n$ does not necessarily equal $N$. We can view $f$ as a function of $\boldsymbol{x}$ or a function of $\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$, $f(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{w}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}+w_0=\boldsymbol{\bar{w}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\bar{x}}=f(\boldsymbol{\bar{x}})$. If you want, in my question, you can replace $f(\boldsymbol{\bar{x_i}})$ by $f(\boldsymbol{x_i})$.

Comment: Not connected;  see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N,n positive integers;  * dot product;  |A| cardinality A
D = ((a1,d1),.. (a_N,d_N)) in (R^n x {-1,1})^N

L:R^n x R -> Z, (x,r) -> |{ i in {1,.. N} : (a_i*x + r).d_i < 0 }|
For k in Z, is L^-1(k) connected?  Is L^-1(k) simply connected?

No.  D = ((0^n,-1), (0^n,1)) is counter example.
(a_1*x + r)d_1 = -r;  (a_2*x + r)d_2 = r

L(x,0) = 0;  r /= 0 implies L(x,r) = 1;  L^-1(1) = R^n x (R - {0})

Comment: May be some typos in your answer: "D = { (a1,d1),.. (a_N,d_N) } subset (R^n x {-1,1})^N" should be "D = ((a1,d1),...,(a_N,d_N)) in (R^n x {-1,1})^N", and "d_i in {0,1}" should be "d_i in {-1,1}"

Comment: Here you misunderstand about function $L$, it not a function from $R^n$ to $Z$. Using your notation, $L$ is defined as: $L: R^n \times  R \rightarrow Z, x \times r\mapsto \{i\in \{1,...,N\}:(a_i * x+r)d_i<0\}$ . So, in your example, domain of $L$ is $R^2$, then your argument is wrong.

Comment: Is a value of L a subset of {1,...,N} or the cardinality thereof?

Comment: See edited revision.

Comment: there is an error in my comment above, change $"L: R^n \times  R \rightarrow Z, x \times r\mapsto \{i\in \{1,...,N\}:(a_i * x+r)d_i<0\}"$  to $"L: R^n \times  R \rightarrow Z, x \times r\mapsto |\{i\in \{1,...,N\}:(a_i * x+r)d_i<0\}|"$.